# Get value of an XML attribute with Groovy (gpath)

Tags: xml, groovy, gpath

Using XmlParser() in groovy.
See the following code. I need to  print the  value of *answer* when the value of *name* is *type*.

```
   <root>
        <foo name = 'type' answer  = 'car'/>
        <foo name = 'color' answer = 'red'/>
        <foo name = 'size' answer = 'big'/>
    </root>
```

I need to do something like this:

```
def XML = new XmlParser().parseText(XMLstring)
println XML.root.foo.[where  @name = 'type'].@answer
```

Comment: Have you tried googling? The [first hit](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Reading+XML+using+Groovy%27s+XmlSlurper) already shows `findAll` usage

Answer (score 12):

I can't tell if you expect there to be multiple matches or if you know there will be exactly one.  The following will find them all and print their answer.

```
source = '''
<root>
    <foo name = 'type' answer  = 'car'/>
    <foo name = 'color' answer = 'red'/>
    <foo name = 'size' answer = 'big'/>
</root>
'''
xml = new XmlParser().parseText(source)

results = xml.findAll { it.@name == 'type' }

results.each {
    println it.@answer
}
```

I hope that helps.

**EDIT:**

If you know there is only one you can do something like this...

```
println xml.find { it.@name == 'type' }.@answer
```

Yet another option (you have several):

```
xml = new XmlParser().parseText(source)

xml.each { 
    if(it.@name == 'type') {
        println it.@answer
    }
}
```